# Why is my web have a split colour in the background

Tags: css, background, background-color

My webpage (a web im doing to learn) have the background splitted in two parts.

[image]

Here is the css code

```
body {
  background: #466368;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50);
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50);
  background:         linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50);    
}
```

Comment: could you please post all the HTML and CSS codes used in this part?

Answer (score 1):

your background is repeating due to the height of the body try this:

```
body {
    background: #466368 no-repeat center center fixed;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background: linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem

```
body{
     background: #466368;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50);
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50);
  background:         linear-gradient(#648880, #293f50);
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Seems splited because your `linear-gradient` is taking the `height` of your content and after that is repeating again. Simply set `no-repeat`  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWZrdo

Comment: doesnt work. the botton part now is white., i solve it by adding `margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;`

and `html{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}`